# QStackedWidget Window Communication

Tags: python, pyqt5

I Have a main.py file and two QMainWindow.py files as well. When a PushButton is clicked on the second QMainWindow.py file it should open a first QStackedWidget, and on the first QStackedWidget when a PushButton is clicked it should show a second QStackedWidget window.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

from mainmenu import MainWindow



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**mainMenu.py**

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.ui.Reg_Emp_Button.clicked.connect(self.manage_reg_Employees)
    self.ui.Report_Button.clicked.connect(self.Employee_Report)


def manage_reg_Employees(self):
    self.hide()
    self.employeeWindow = EmployeeWindow(self)
    self.employeeWindow.show()



def Employee_Report(self):
    self.hide()
    self.chartWindow = ChartWindow(self)
    self.chartWindow.show()
```

**ManageEmployee.py**

```
class EmployeeWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, mainMenu):
        super(EmployeeWindow, self).__init__()
        self.mainMenu = mainMenu

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.Back_Button.clicked.connect(self.Back_To_MainMenu)
        self.ui.Add_Employee_Button_2.clicked.connect(self.Add_New_Employee)

   def Back_To_MainMenu(self):
       self.hide()

       self.mainMenu.show()
```

Comment: What is your question? What *specific* programming problem do you want help with?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your response I have gotten a solution to it. I used QStackedWidget in solving it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.